# Is there any way to remove "Highlight" menuItem in iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a CustomPDFView where I have return false for `override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool` but still getting "Highlight" menuItem when the text is selected. How to get rid of this or is there any way to to set a custom action when it is tapped? As it doesn't highlight the text automatically.

[image: SCREEN SHOT]